# Geofencing Android is not working

Tags: android, gps, geofencing

atm i working at a application which is using Geofencing.
The App should notificait the users, if they reach a defined area.

If i use FakeGPS from the AppStore to set the Location, the App alerts a notification.

But if i walk there, with GPS activated, nothing is happen.

Did someone of you know the different, why the one option is working and the other not?
Just a Question at all, if you need my code i can post it, but its pretty much.

Also the GPS Icon is now shown (whats normal happen, if i use a app with GPS)
A bit help would be nice

Comment: its might be because of GPS interval , try to make distance 0 in 0 sec. and also which api your using for location?

Comment: damn forgott to activate the listener ... bad idea to programm at this time in the morning. Anyway thx